# VTOL Propeller Sizing and Executing a transition from VTOL to Forward Flight mission profile

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rotorcraft, vtol

Hi I am an engineering student, currently in the process of designing a compound UAV drone capable of both vertical and forward flight. I've made significant progress, having completed initial gross weight estimation, Wing Loading and powerloading estimation, wing, fuselage, tail, powerplant, and landing gear design, as well as weight estimations. Moreover, I've solved for the center of gravity at each component location using equations from Daniel Raymer and Mohammad Sadraey, resulting in minimal CG travel.
This is the UAV that I have designed:
[image]

However, all these calculations have been based on single-engine estimations from Raymer as advised by my professor. My current hurdle lies in the VTOL (Vertical Takeoff and Landing) mission profile. I'm unsure about the rule of thumb for determining the diameter of the VTOL propellers and whether it's a critical aspect. Unfortunately, my professor hasn't provided much guidance regarding the VTOL motors.

Another challenge I'm facing is how to execute the required mission profile, as depicted below:
[image]

According to my professor, I need to gradually reduce the RPM of the VTOL mechanism while increasing the RPM of the pusher propeller. However, I'm concerned that this approach might impose excessive torque on my VTOL propeller. My alternative proposal is to go power-off once a certain height is reached and then increase the RPM of my pusher propeller as the aircraft glides. Nonetheless, I'm uncertain if the airfield space would be adequate for this specific mission profile.

Any advice or guidance on these issues would be greatly appreciated.